# SGDClassifier : Get the weights and bias for each training step

Tags: scikit-learn

I would like to get the coef_ (weight vector) and the intercept_ (bias) for each iteration or training step for the sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.

However, I cannot find anywhere such a functionality? Is this even possible with sklearn?

In tensorflow I could add a callback. Is there something similar available for SGDClassifier?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`partial_fit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit) method to get the results of a single training epoch for `sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier`.